# Removing a clicked cloned div

Tags: jquery

I have cloned a div and in this div i have several buttons amongst theme a delete button.Once i click the delete button,a div that wasn't clicked is being deleted instead of the clicked one.I have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/qBYzf/

Here is the function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        $("<div class='newclone' id='xxx'><article><label>Firstname</label><input type='text'><label>Secondname</label><input type='text'><label>City</label><input type='text'><input type='hidden' value='4'></article><button class='one'>Save</button><button class='two'>Delete</button><button class='three'>Cancel</button></div>").appendTo('.clone-container');
    });
    $('.two').live("click", function() {
        $('#xxx').fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
});
```

How can i remove the clicked div?.

Comment: The fiddle you provided works perfectly for me!

Comment: Try typing something on one div and try removing it.The topmost div get removed and not the clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `closest()`, see **updated** fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/qBYzf/1/

So you needed to change:

```
$('#xxx')
```

To:

```
$(this).closest('#xxx')
```

---

Also you are assigning same `id=xxx` to each cloned div. **The `id` should be unique per element**, use a `class` instead or different `id` value for it to be valid as per W3C rules/standards.

**Documentation:**

- http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
$(this).closest('#xxx').fadeOut(....
```

instead of:

```
$('#xxx').fadeOut(...
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YazH2/)

Though that will work, but in no case you should have two ids having same value in the same page , this does not comply with W3C standards.